# Why is this object being deallocated?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, exception, memory-management

I'm developing an iPhone app, I'm trying to push a view into the navigation controller, which I've done many times before, however, I'm having some issues with this particular app. I have a table view, and when the user selects one row the new view is pushed into the controller:

```
DataWrapper *row=[[self.rows objectAtIndex:[indexPath section]] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
DataViewController *nextController=[[DataViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Data" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[nextController setInfo:row];
[nextController setRow:[indexPath row]];
[nextController setParent:self];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:nextController animated:YES];
[nextController release];
```

and it goes fine, until the user taps the back button, I get an exception, and used NSZombieEnabled and get this:

```
-[DataViewController respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x4637a00
```

So i tried to remove the `[nextController release]` and in fact it worked, but WHY???? I allocated nextController, so I'm supposed to release it, right?? I don't feel right releasing this app if there's something like this, I feel like it's going to fail. Please let me know your thoughts.

Comment: anything special happening in the parent controller's view(Will/Did)Appear? Maybe something involving another instance variable that wasn't retained or was over released?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `nextController` isn't being retained by navigation controller. If you release it then because there is only one `init/release` pair, the object is deallocated. Later when the `navigationController` attempts to send messages to it, you get the error you see.

This is also why remove `[nextController release]` fixes the problem.

You are right in that if you allocated, you should free it. But the caveat is only *after* your application is done with it, not *before*.

Some objects will stay allocated for nearly the lifetime of the application, so don't feel too bad.

Comment: I think the clean way would be to allocate the `DataViewController` in the `- viewDidLoad` method and then deallocate it again in the `- viewDidUnload` method.

Comment: I see, I thougt that when you use pushViewController the NavigationController takes ownership of the object. I'll try to alloc the controller in viewDidLoad.

Comment: @Leg10n: unless the documentation specifically says a method will `retain` an object, or an property has setters which `retain`, never assume another object will take ownership.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that `[self.navigationController]` is returning `nil`, because if it weren't `nil`, it would be retaining your object.  Since your object is not getting retained, it would appear that there is no object that's trying to retain it, indicating that the `navigationController` property is empty.

Comment: That doesn't explain why it works though... if that was being called on `nil`, the screen would never show up.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that your navigation controller is somehow being deallocated, resulting in the view controllers also getting released? You could maybe test it by retaining the nav controller just before pushing `nextController`.

Answer (score 0):

For debugging purposes, I would override `-dealloc` in your DataViewController class, and set a breakpoint on it.

Answer (score 0):

but it seems to work for something like:

```
DetailViewController *controller = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SomeView" bundle:nil]; 

controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
[self presentModalViewController: controller animated:NO];

[controller release];
```

so, why is it not working for pushViewController ?